# Strikethrough in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, text-formatting

Is there anyway I can have text with strikethrough style in Notepad++? I use Notepad++ for my to-do lists, and being able to assign strikethrough to the highlighted text (especially if it could be on a keyboard shortcut) would be very useful.

**Just to clarify**: I realise that strikethrough is formatted text, and not that of a text editor. My query was more if there was something (a plugin maybe) that did some kind of markup which it rendered as strikethrough. I'm guessing not, but worth asking.

Comment: I believe you are looking for a word processor, not a text editor.

Comment: @Phoshi Was more just wondering if with all the notepad++ plugins, if there was something that embedded some markup which handled this. I realise that strikethrough is formatted text, not standard text.

Answer (score 22):

I'm also seeking a solution for this problem (using Strikethrough for a to-do list).  I couldn't find a plugin and I think creating one would be the best way to go.

As a work-around until that happens, what I'm doing is setting the language of my to-do list (a .txt file) to the "Properties" language.  Then, when I'm done with that task, I put a '#' in front of it to make a comment (which color-codes the line as green and you can customize the color).  Not as good as a strike-through but it gets the job done.

Comment: Thanks. Good soln. until we get a strike though plugin for notepad++

Comment: I made this comment a year ago, and I don't use notepad++ for to-do lists anymore.  I use OneNote, and you can add "To-do" tags by pressing "Ctrl+1" (which makes a checkbox for you).  A webapp is available, as well as a mobile app.  Just another option to consider.

Comment: Great suggestion, and I used this method to actually create strikethroughs, as follows: Edit the style of the Properties language by going to Settings > Style Configurator. Now, in 'Font Style', change the default font to a Strikethrough font.  I used 'BPtypewriteStrikethrough' which I found here: http://www.1001fonts.com/strikethrough-fonts.html (once-off install). Personally, I opted to change the green font to gray, which is less distracting.

Answer (score 9):

You could right click on the line and use one of the marking styles (Using 1st Style, etc.). That won't do strikethrough, but it will highlight the line in a background you can choose by selecting which style and configure the styles in Settings > Style Configurator.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have option to strikethrough your style, you can set style to use some strikethrough font. This should be easy to find and download.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is like a year+ later, but there is a feature in Notepad++ to "Hide Lines" just highlight and right click. Then at the bottom of the menu, there is a Hide Lines feature which Hides a specified line and then can be clicked to be reopened. Also, On the left side next to the line number you can click on the line number and it will put a blue circle which can act as a checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Style it with colors for now as

[image]

Or you can also put breakpoints like this:

[image: like this]

But if you want to send that document to someone then I will prefer [@Atif's answer](https://superuser.com/a/395523/167207)
"put a prefix like #"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

##### Enable Support for Strikethrough in Notepad++:

1. Download the font BPtypewrite (https://www.1001fonts.com/download/bptypewrite.zip) or any other font that support strikethrough option by default.
2. Extract zip file then install individual font files by right clicking on it and from context menu hit the install option. Check details here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-font-b7c5f17c-4426-4b53-967f-455339c564c1
3. Open Notepad++ > Go to Top Menu > Language > User Defined Language > Define your language > This will open a popup window
4. Update the popup form as mentioned below -

   - User language: Select "Markdown (preinstalled)" from dropdown
   - Click on "Operators & Delimiters" tab
   - Modify Delimiter 8 style option as below

     ```
     Open: ~~
     Escape: \
     Close: ~~
     ```
   - Click on Styler > This will open Styler Dialog
   - Update "Font options" as below:

     - **Name**: BPtypewriteStrikethrogh
     - **Size**: 10
   - Click on "OK" button

##### Testing:

1. Now open a new file in Notepad++
2. Go to Top Menu > Language > Markdown (Preinstalled)
3. Type: ~~This is a strike through text~~
4. This will show text in Strikethrough font.
5. Tested version: v8.5.5 (64-bit)
   [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFTpK.png)